# Replace characters outside a characterset

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a string wherein I want to replace some characters which are not matching my required character set to one space each. So if there are 3 characters replaced, there should be 3 spaces.

My required character set =

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789/?().,' "+&
```

====> includes space

Code that I have tried so far.

```
str    = "AC!@+D^*$ASS1@AC!@+D^*$ASS1@AC!@+D^*$ASS1@£ PPP    IE"
expstr = "AC  +D   ASS1 AC  +D   ASS1 AC  +D   ASS1   PPP    IE"

Set objRegX = New RegExp
objRegX.Pattern  = "[^A-Za-z0-9/?().,''+& ']"
str = objRegX.Replace(str, " ")
```

Please help.

My expected String is the value in the variable 'expstr'. Whereas the 'str' variable is printing the below

```
AC @+D^*$ASS1@AC!@+D^*$ASS1@AC!@+D^*$ASS1@£ PPP    IE
```

I need it like the below

```
AC  +D   ASS1 AC  +D   ASS1 AC  +D   ASS1   PPP    IE
```

Comment: Please state your question clearly. There is no question here.

Comment: Well, it looks like the pattern [does the job correctly](https://regex101.com/r/KadrDt/1). What is the problem? You just need not triple the single apostrophe. `[^A-Za-z0-9/?().,'+& ]` is enough.

Comment: Apologies for that... I have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Global` property to `True`:

```
objRegX.Global = True
```

If you need to exlude the double quote as well, escape it with another double quote, instead of using two single quotes:

```
objRegX.Pattern  = "[^A-Za-z0-9/?().,""+& ']"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this!

Comment: I will accept the answer once the site lets me accept it :)